# Can I drop one of these indexes in Wordpress?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

i'm currently exceeding the maximum server queries per hour with my blog on my host, and when that happens they shut my account down, rendering it useless.

I keep exceeding the maximum amount of queries which is 75,000 but I don't think I should be considering the amount of visitors I have at the moment, plus I'm using Super Cache.

I've been trying to investigate what may be causing the problem, but I've had little luck so far.

I've tried:

- Repairing the tables
- Optimizing the tables
- Removing dead references from wp_options
- Dropping unused tables

However, I did notice this warning:

[image]

Am I right in thinking this may be the problem? If not does anyone have any other ideas for me to explore?

Thanks.

Comment: That would not cause the excess query problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your plugins if any of them explicitly use the option_name_2 index, if so remove that from the plugin (I would drop the plugin completely, it sounds like a bad plugin) and then drop the index.

I would also check your theme and make sure it only uses one call to the DB for it's options. I recently came across a theme that still stored every option separately in the DB.

PS the can be fixed pretty easily.

Comment: Is there a quick way to check, or do I literally have to go through each php file in the plugin editor?

Answer (score 3):

That is not your problem, you can drop that indexes but that will not reduce the number of queries you have.
Try asking for a mysql log to see what is being queried, or disabling plugins/widgets that can be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at your web server logs to see if you're really getting that number of hits on your blog, and if they are getting the cached version or going straight to the database.  The other thing to look is to see if your MySQL port is open to the outside world - it's possible that somebody is hitting your database directly for nefarious purposes.